# How to tell Symfony 3 to ignore certain annotations?

Tags: annotations, symfony

I'm developing an API with Symfony 3 and I want to use [apidoc](http://apidocjs.com/) to create a documentation. Apidoc works with annotations:

```
/**
 * @api {get} /user/:id Request User information
 * @apiName GetUser
 * @apiGroup User
 *
 * @apiParam {Number} id Users unique ID.
 *
 * @apiSuccess {String} firstname Firstname of the User.
 * @apiSuccess {String} lastname  Lastname of the User.
 */
```

But Symfony throws an annotation exception:

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@apiName" in method
>   AppBundle\Controller\API\ApiLoginController::loginAction() was never
>   imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this
>   annotation?
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - AnnotationException

Is there any way to tell symfony to ignore those annotations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered [NelmioApiDocBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html) instead? I'm not certain if apidoc will work with Symfony.

Comment: Yes, I know that bundle and I'll use it if there's no other option, but I already have experience with apidoc, I like the results and I don't have too much time right now to learn how to handle another Bundle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an @IgnoreAnnotation [Doctrine annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information) you can use. Try this:

```
/**
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("api")
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("apiName")
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("apiGroup")
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("apiParam")
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("apiSuccess")
 */
class SomeController extends Controller{
...
    /**
     * @api {get} /user/:id Request User information
     * @apiName GetUser
     * @apiGroup User
     *
     * @apiParam {Number} id Users unique ID.
     *
     * @apiSuccess {String} firstname Firstname of the User.
     * @apiSuccess {String} lastname  Lastname of the User.
     */
```

The documentation is further down in that link.

Comment: I had to modify my original post. You should put the `@IgnoreAnnotation` at the beginning of the Controller or Class.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

There is also a way to [ignore an annotation globally](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.6/annotations.html). We didn't want to annotate each class, so we added this to our bootstrap file `web/app.php`.

```
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('your-custom-annotation');
```