# custom class extends tcpdf in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, tcpdf

```
class PdfTemplateController extends TCPDF{}
```

gives error message :

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@public" in method TCPDF::__destruct() was never imported. Did you maybe forget
>         to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in C:\xampp\htdocs\myworkspace\ApartmentManagementSystem\ApartmentMan
>         agementScms\src\AppBundle/Controller/ (which is being imported from "C:\xampp\htdocs\myworkspace\ApartmentManagemen
>         tSystem\ApartmentManagementScms/app/config\routing.yml"). Make sure annotations are installed and enabled.
>
> In AnnotationException.php line 54:
>
> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@public" in method TCPDF::__destruct() was never imported. Did you maybe forget
>      to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Comment: You can use `@IgnoreAnnotation("public")` on your class. I will vote to close this, as it seems like a copy of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496487/how-to-tell-symfony-3-to-ignore-certain-annotations

Comment: This doesn't work, still getting the same error :                                                   
                                                                                                                       /**
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("public")
 */
class PdfTemplateController extends \TCPDF{}

Comment: Thank you, after I wrote annotation beforfe TCPDF(i.e Super Class) its working ...